# How do I decrypt arduino IR sendRC5()?

Tags: arduino, remote-control

I am trying to make an arduino Uno and Mega communicate with each other over IR, but I am having trouble decrypting the output.

Uno code:

```
#include <IRremote.h>
IRsend irsend;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
    irsend.sendRC5(i, 3);
    delay(500);
  }
}
```

Mega code:

```
#include <IRremote.h>
#define RECV_PIN 3
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
irrecv.enableIRIn();
}
void loop() {
if (irrecv.decode(&results)){
  int state;
  if ( results.value == 1 ){
    state = HIGH;
  }
  else{
    state = LOW;
  }
  Serial.println(results.value, DEC);
  irrecv.resume();
  }
}
```

Serial output:

```
08:59:57.562 -> 819043197
08:59:58.072 -> 4239130558
08:59:58.586 -> 4092259158
08:59:59.094 -> 1271936904
08:59:59.604 -> 1322269761
09:00:00.119 -> 3687369585
09:00:00.625 -> 1513342804
09:00:01.136 -> 869376052
09:00:01.648 -> 819043197
09:00:02.157 -> 4239130558
09:00:02.669 -> 4092259158
09:00:03.180 -> 1271936904
09:00:03.691 -> 1322269761
```

Is there some kind of decrypt function, or do I have to map each output manually, for 500 outputs?  I have joysticks that can return any value in that range.

Comment: The serial output is obviously a small section, the ir will go forever

Comment: Read/Run the examples that came with the library, judging from your code, you don't know how it is works yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a bad library, updating it fixed the problem